# Comparing ip addresses in bpftrace?

Tags: networking, ebpf, kprobe, bpftrace

I am writing some [`bpftrace`](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace) code in which I would like to compare an IP address (stored as a 32 bit integer) against the string representation of an address. That is, I want to do something like this:

```
kprobe:netif_receive_skb {
  $skb = (struct sk_buff *)arg0;
  $dev = $skb->dev;
  $name = $dev->name;
  $ipheader = ((struct iphdr *) ($skb->head + $skb->network_header));

  // This pseudocode conditional is what I am trying to figure out
  if ($ipheader->daddr == "8.8.8.8") {
    printf("%s %s %s -> %s\n",
        func, $name, ntop($ipheader->saddr), ntop($ipheader->daddr))
  }
}
```

In the above, `$ipheader` is a `struct iphdr *`, and `struct iphdr` looks like [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/ip.h#L86):

```
struct iphdr {
  ...
  __struct_group(/* no tag */, addrs, /* no attrs */,
    __be32  saddr;
    __be32  daddr;
  );
};
```

So both `saddr` and `daddr` are unsigned 32-bit integers.

I thought perhaps I could use the `pton()` function, like this:

```
if ($ipheader->daddr == pton("8.8.8.8")) {
```

But unfortunately `pton()` returns an `int8[4]` array instead of a single 32 bit integer, so this fails with:

```
traceit.bpf:8:5-41: ERROR: Type mismatch for '==': comparing 'unsigned int32' with 'unsigned int8[4]'
    if ($ipheader->daddr == pton("8.8.8.8")) {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I next tried to see if I could normalize both values into `int8[4]` arrays, like this:

```
$target = pton("8.8.8.8");
$daddr = pton(ntop($ipheader->daddr));
if ($target == $daddr) {
```

But *this* fails because `ntop()` doesn't actually return a string, so we get:

```
ERROR: Expected string literal, got inet
traceit.bpf:9:10-38: ERROR: pton() expects an string argument of an IPv4/IPv6 address, got
$daddr = pton(ntop($ipheader->daddr));
```

I realize I could just specify the target as an integer myself:

```
if ($ipheader->daddr == 0x08080808) {
```

But while that's easy to interpret for a contrived address like 8.8.8.8, it's opaque when the hex form of the address is something like `0xacd9004e`.

Is it possible to compare a 32-bit integer representation of an address with the string representation of an address using `bpftrace` (and if so, what's the canonical way of doing so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 0.17 and 0.19:

- 0.17 added support for comparing int arrays
- 0.19 added support for casting int to int array

Both of these should allow comparing IP addresses by casting them to a common type.

Answer (score -1):

if the $ipheader->daddr is 192.168.2.44, just convert this four number to hex chars, which are `c0 a8 02 2c`. reversal chars are `2c 02 a8 c0`. so you can just write:

```
if ($ipheader->daddr == 0x2c02a8c0) {
...
}
```